# Why am I getting the error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tbl_Registration_F260DE.....',

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**getting a error**

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tbl_Registration_F260DE0649B1F8A99D1E75ED9548854811A0E22A5BE146F4EF69B9A7DB65ED97', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BTK_ES.Models.Tbl_Notification'.*

how can I solve it below Is my code i just want to show user data in input fields so user can edit

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult StudentDetails(int Registration_ID)
  {
      var result = dbContext.Tbl_Registration.Where(move => move.Registration_ID == Registration_ID).FirstOrDefault();

      if (result != null)
      {
          ViewBag.Class_ID = dbContext.Tbl_Class
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = c.Class_ID.ToString(),
              Text = c.Class_Name
          })
          .ToList();
          return View(result);
      }
      else
      {
          return HttpNotFound(); 
      }
  }
```

and this is the code of my view

```
@model BTK_ES.Models.Tbl_Registration
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tbl_Registration</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Registration_ID)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameOfApplicant, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameOfApplicant, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameOfApplicant, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```